# Set Autoshrink UILabel but not run in Xcode 9 in two device (iPhone 8 and iPhone 4S simulators)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Autoshrink UILabel not adjust in iPhone 8 and iPhone 4S with Xcode 9

Iphone 8 wC hR and iPhone 4S has same width and height. I set minimum font scale with 0,5 but in image show AAAAAAA with same size.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autoshrink only shrinks the font if the text that you are trying to display is too wide to display in the constrained area.  The UILabel itself doesn't know anything about screen size.  It only tells if the constraints squeeze it.

If you want to preview in the Interface Builder, you can select the size your trying to display and see how the UILabel responds to the different screen sizes.[image]